# this python script can be shortened/optimized, how?

Tags: python

I'm not used to doing things the python way yet, but I'm almost certain the following script can be condensed. I'm not looking for speed optimization here, I'm looking for more readable code. Make it slower for all I care, but what are some ways to make this look more Python-esque.

I'm simply reading in a csv file filled with zipcodes and populating a database with 23 columns. Lots of typing. I also don't like hard coding things like the index of the row. Also, multis = '%s, '*23 followed by multis = multis[:-2] feels dirty.

Looking forward to see what some of you can come up with.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", db="test")
c = db.cursor()
f_csv = 'zip-codes-database-STANDARD.csv'
csvReader = csv.reader(open(f_csv))
ziplist = []
multis = '%s, '*23
multis = multis[:-2]
for row in csvReader:
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO lock_zipcodes_complete 
            (`zipcode`, `city`, `state`, `county`, `areacode`,
            `citytype`, `city_alias_abbreviation`,
            `city_alias_name`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `timezone`,
            `elevation`, `county_fips`, `dst`,
            `preferred_last_line_key`, `classification_code`,
            `multicounty`, `state_fips`, `city_state_key`,
            `city_alias_code`, `primary_record`, `city_mixed_case`,
            `city_alias_mixed_case`) VALUES(""" + multis + ')',
            (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6],
            row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12],
            row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18],
            row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22]))
```

Comment: You want it shorter than 10 lines of code!?

Comment: Not shorter, I was just looking ways to make it not as verbose. I knew the way I'm using the tuple row above is incorrect. Also the multis string. just wanted some python gurus to show an example of how they'd change it so I can learn.

Comment: Neither answer so far has explained why this is so, but note your query has a danger of a "SQL injection attack" and is generally considered a very dangerous way to use databases.  (Safe in this case if you control the input data, but a bad habit to get into.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part:

```
multis = '%s, '*23
multis = multis[:-2]
```

should be

```
multis = ', '.join(['%s'] * 23)
```

`ziplist` is not used, so you can just remove the line that sets it.

```
            (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6],
            row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12],
            row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18],
            row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22])
```

should be just `tuple(row)` (for the specific way you're using it, just `row` will do).

The explicit list of column names in the `INSERT` is unpleasant, but needed if you're unsure whether that's all columns in that DB table or whether the order is right (or, of course, if you're sure that either is not the case); but that's a SQL - vs - CSV "impedence mismatch" issue rather that a Python one;-).

The whole loop:

```
for row in csvReader:
  c.execute(sql_statement, row)
```

can, optionally, further be compacted to:

```
c.executemany(sql_statement, csvReader)
```

Comment: Explicitly listing column names is always a good idea - resist the urge to not use it, even if your input data conforms.  If you list the column names in your insert statements (something that won't cost you much typing if you just store it), then refactoring your database later becomes a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not build SQL text like that.  Please do not.  Please.

First.  The variable `ziplist` is not used.  Delete it.

Second.  Use real SQL binding.

```
c.execute( "INSERT...", row )
```

This is documented in the MySQLdb interface.  http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/.